# Tooltip Hidden in Code section of Ask Question page

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets, tooltips

In chrome version:62.0.3202.62, zoom is 100%, Tooltip in code section of ask question page is hidden behind the content area.

Here is the screenshot for your reference, how to fix this issue??

[image]

Comment: Strange, I'm also on Chrome but can't repro

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce if the zoom is larger than 150%.  What size is your screen?

Comment: Browser window width: 1440
Browser window height: 699
Screen width: 1440
Screen height: 900

Comment: If i use full screen, tooltip is coming without any issue, if it is minimized screen, tooltip is hidden